# IntelliJ - build error

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

Out of nowhere I get this error when trying to build my project. Everything was running ok and I didn't do an update or anything else that could've messed up the IDE. I simply restarted the IDE as it started to be slow without any real reason.
I searched for solutions on forums and other questions, but those are old should be fixed by the new updates for IntelliJ. What could've happened?

```
  Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':libs:facebook:processReleaseResources'.
    > java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "D:\AndroidSDK\build-tools\20.0.0\aapt.exe": CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
```

**UPDATE:**

After an complete system restart it seems to work again. But this is an weird error, that I haven't seen before and I'm very curious of what could generate it.

Comment: There was no update from the last time it worked. Not for Android SDK and not for the IntelliJ IDE. 
What could generate this kind of error ?

Comment: I find that it helps me a lot to cut & paste error messages into Google.  I usually find out that I'm neither alone nor the first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853529/createprocess-error-740-the-requested-operation-requires-elevation

Comment: I have searched for the error before posting on SO and I already saw that question, but the link from the accepted answer does not work anymore, and the other answers did not provide an answer for my problem.

Comment: As far as I know, restarting the IDE will not restart the Gradle Daemon (try `gradlew --stop`), so the problem *could* be related to that. PS: This doesn't make a good SO question, and should instead be reported to the Android Studio project.

Comment: I think you are right about this, I suspect the problem was gradle itself. As the OS restart fixed the issue.