# java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, eclipse

My code:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command("n");

File file = new File("..");
builder.directory( file );

try {
        Process p = builder.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Eclipse says:

```
java.io.IOException
Cannot run program "n" (in directory ".."): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

But the file n.txt is there, if I say:

```
for(String fileNames : file.list()) System.out.println(fileNames);
```

It's listed: n.txt.
Same problem if I substitute "`n.txt`" with "`n`" in the sourcecode or try to call a `.exe`;

```
System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
```

Creates

```
F:\Programme\eclipse\workspaces\test
```

This:

```
System.out.println(builder.directory().getAbsolutePath());
```

Creates

```
F:\Programme\eclipse\workspaces\SimulatorAddOn\SimulatorAddOn\..
```

And substituting

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command("n");
```

with

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("n");
```

Doesn't change anything either.

I need your help guys.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to run a text file? If you want to open it with the default program, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550329/how-to-open-a-file-with-the-default-associated-program

Comment: like i said, i actually try to run a .exe in the same folder. if I say
                                 Desktop.getDesktop().open( file);
n.txt opens, but I have to adjust to
                                 File file = new File("..\\n.txt");

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason why the system cannot find the file is that the `directory` method only sets the working directory of processes that are run by the builder (from the Javadocs):

> Sets this process builder's working directory. Subprocesses subsequently started by this object's start() method will use this as their working directory.

So you need this:

```
builder.command("..\\n.txt");
```

for the system to find your file. This still won't do anything useful, you'll get an error similar to:

```
Cannot run program "..\n.txt" (in directory ".."): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

The process builder requires a valid appication in your operating system.

Comment: builder will look for the file in the current working directory, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java for how to get it.

Comment: I didn't explain myself very well the first time: I'm actually tring to run an exe. If I use your idea with .command("..\test.exe");
it says now: The requested operation requires elevation

Comment: @murkr The process you're trying to run cannot due to some security issue, which is a whole other question! Looks like it might be something to do with Windows UAC [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5853529/1879990)