# Jenkins/Pom.xml fails when the run

Tags: xml, maven, selenium, jenkins, webdriver

When i run my pom.xml through Jenkins am getting the below error and not able to compile the program.

```
Building in workspace C:\Users\test\.jenkins\workspace\mavenBuild
Installing C:\Users\test\.jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\C_Program_Files_x86_Java_jdk1.8.0_25\jdk.exe
[C_Program_Files_x86_Java_jdk1.8.0_25] $ C:\Users\test\.jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\C_Program_Files_x86_Java_jdk1.8.0_25\jdk.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature" REBOOT=ReallySuppress INSTALLDIR=C:\Users\test\.jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\C_Program_Files_x86_Java_jdk1.8.0_25 /L C:\Users\test\.jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\install5805825604689233021log
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\test\.jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\C_Program_Files_x86_Java_jdk1.8.0_25\jdk.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\test\.jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\C_Program_Files_x86_Java_jdk1.8.0_25"): CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:245)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:214)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:846)
hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:544)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 22 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: "Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation".

Comment: what is the solution????

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853529/createprocess-error-740-the-requested-operation-requires-elevation helps.

Comment: @ShanmugaRaj The error says it all `Installing C:\Users\test\.jenkins\tools\hudson.model.JDK\C_Program_Files_x86_Java_jdk1.8.0_25\jdk.exe` Probhably you havn't set the JDK path in Jenkins or you might have misconfigured the path in the batch file. Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks for the response....I can able to run the build successfully but still am getting error like below:                                               java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)

Comment: @ShanmugaRaj Can you please update your code block & the entire stack trace in the Question area for further analysis? Thanks

Comment: @ShanmugaRaj Can you consider to do a `maven clean` and `maven install` before executing through Jenkins? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB ya sure...but is it right to give maven clean maven install in Jenkins Build > Goals and options text area?

Comment: @ShanmugaRaj Yes, that is the ideal way we should do. Incase you are doubtful, to start with perform `maven clean` & `maven install` through Eclipse. Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB please find the error code here:              [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44301356/jenkins-pom-xml-throws-error)

Comment: @ShanmugaRaj So now your Jenkins error being resolved, should I construct an Answer for you to Accept it as a solution? Thanks

Comment: ya but am getting different error now...did u saw tat error which i mentioned in the link???@DebanjanB

Comment: @ShanmugaRaj You are getting different error because you have not configured configured maven properly. Try to execute `maven test` from command line first. Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks..my issue got resolved...i just downgrade my maven to lower version