# Could not run exe file through java code, in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, runtime, exe

I am trying to execute an exe file through Java code. I wrote below a simple code in Eclipse but got error. Tried multiple solutions but all in vain.

My code:

```
package com.runExeFile;

import java.io.File;

public class ClassA {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\FlashBuild\\14_09_2017_play_27_0_r0_137\\FF_32Release\\Something.exe");
    }

}
```

The Error I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\FlashBuild\14_09_2017_play_27_0_r0_137\FF_32Release\install_flash_player_27_plugin.exe": CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at com.runExeFile.ClassA.main(ClassA.java:9)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)`enter code here`
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: It's what the error states: You have to run the program with elevated permissions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853529/createprocess-error-740-the-requested-operation-requires-elevation)

Answer (score 1):

It is because you need to run the program as administrator. To run the program as administrator here is the code. Error 740 is because of that only. 
See these link

[CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853529/createprocess-error-740-the-requested-operation-requires-elevation)

[Java: run as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385866/java-run-as-administrator)

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class RunAsAdminExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Process myappProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powershell.exe Start-Process notepad.exe -verb RunAs");
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally got success with below line of code but still i did not get how it works.                                                                                                                                                                       Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler "+PathOfExe);

Answer (score 0):

I had done it recently. and the way I did was

```
try {
    File fileDirectory = new File("C:/someDirectory");
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd","/C","start someRunnable.exe"}, null, fileDirectory);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which you needed to specify the directory to run and the start Command prompt to run the executable.